# How to run a .jar application as a service (Start on boot of system)

Tags: systemd, 17.04

Ok I'll make this quick. I'm developing a client-server app with an Ubuntu 17.04 server as the server. In that server is a jar containing all the server-side code.

The code just binds some sockets and continuously listen for client requests and makes threads for each request.

The problem is, that I can't get the .jar to startup on system boot. I check this by checking for open ports and none of the ports I coded in ever listen on boot up.

I've tried the following

Startup Applications - didn't work

Systemd - the .sh script works perfectly when I run it nornally, .jar runs and the ports open, but when booting up nothing happens. Using `sudo service bla bla bla start` also runs the app perfectly. It just won't work on boot up

The target specified is `graphical.target` and the unit starts AFTER `mysql.service`

Using init.d - jack shit happens

I'm at my wits end on what to do. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Show us how your systemd service looked like.

Answer (score 0):

i) Create your bash script called mystartup.sh to run the .jar file in /etc/init.d/ directory(login as root)

```
# vi /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh
```

ii) Add commands to this script one by one:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo “Setting up customized environment…”
fortune
```

iii) Setup executable permission on script:

```
# chmod +x /etc/init.d/mystartup.sh
```

iv)Make sure this script get executed every time Debian Linux system boot up/comes up:

```
# update-rc.d mystartup.sh defaults 100
```

To read more follow this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html)

Answer (score -1):

A simple way is provided by the `upstart` package, after installing it just save the following script in `etc/init/onshutdown.conf` :

```
# /etc/init/onshutdown.conf
start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=2
# execute single command
exec /bin/sh /path/to/mystartup.sh
# alternatively without an extra script
script
  java -jar /path/to/jarfile.jar
  # your commands here
end script
```

Replace `2` with your preferred [runlevel(s)](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels) (e. g. `[2345]`). For more information about `upstart` see [man 5 init](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/init.5.html) and [the upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).